# Convert image to PDF with Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Receive multiple images as input from the user and convert them into PDF. I don't understand how to implement it with Django.

Comment: See this library: https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/

Comment: I know that ......but how to implement it in django

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-pdf/ for example. please write some code. there are a million examples out there where people wrote a python script that creates a pdf. If you wonder where to place a script like this -> do some basic tutorials on how django works and where python code is impmeneted. Views.py could be one of that places.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install the packages

```
pip install img2pdf
```

Below is the implementation:

Image can be converted into pdf bytes using img2pdf.convert() functions provided by img2pdf module, then the pdf file opened in wb mode and is written with the bytes.

```
# Python3 program to convert image to pfd 
# using img2pdf library 

# importing necessary libraries 
import img2pdf 
from PIL import Image 
import os 

# storing image path 
img_path = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/GfG_images/do_nawab.png"

# storing pdf path 
pdf_path = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/GfG_images/file.pdf"

# opening image 
image = Image.open(img_path) 

# converting into chunks using img2pdf 
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(image.filename) 

# opening or creating pdf file 
file = open(pdf_path, "wb") 

# writing pdf files with chunks 
file.write(pdf_bytes) 

# closing image file 
image.close() 

# closing pdf file 
file.close() 

# output 
print("Successfully made pdf file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pillow supports PDF format. Documentation is available [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#pdf).

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/path/to/image.jpg')
img = img.convert('RGB') //This removes alpha channel from .png images.
img.save('/path/to/image.pdf', format="PDF")
```